# vim: delete all whitespace characters up to my cursor

Tags: vim, macvim

is there anyway to delete every character on the same line as a cursor, all the way up to the cursor? for instance, I might have a line of code that looks like the following:

```
foo = [cursor]             Bar.new
```

If my cursor is at the place holder above, is it possible to delete every whitespace character (without using regex?) so that Bar.new is placed at the cursor?

Comment: You're asking two separate questions... Do you want to delete whitespace leading to the cursor, or whitespace starting from your cursor up to the next non-whitespace character?

Comment: it should've read *from my cursor up to the start of the next word*, I think

Answer (score 47, accepted):

<kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd>

Answer (score 9):

Based on your example, Neall's answer is correct. However, based on your initial question,

> is there anyway to delete every
>   character on the same line as a
>   cursor, all the way up to the cursor?

you would type <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>

Actually, you're asking a third question in your title... delete all whitespace characters up to the cursor. That one I'm not sure how to do without regex. <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> would remove all the whitespace characters leading backwards until a non-whitespace, but it also deletes the first non-whitespace character.

Comment: Not quite as neat, since you need to know the character you're deleting to, but deleting back to the = could be accomplished with `dT=`.  **D** elete backwards-' **T** il **=**

Answer (score 9):

Not quite what you want, but perhaps <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> would help - in the example above, it would delete *all* the whitespace between the `=` and the `Bar`.  Perhaps <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> would give you the result you are looking for?

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>

Will delete any character up to, but not including the 'B'